# UIView Animation slide in

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview, cgrect

I am trying to get my `UIView` to slide in from the right in the `viewDidLoad` method here's what I've got.

```
CGRect menuFrame = self.menu.frame;
menuFrame.origin.y = menuFrame.size.height+200;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.05
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.menu.frame = menuFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Animation Complete!");

                 }];
```

I am not sure what has gone wrong here I appreciate any help greatly.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't what you asked, but it is worth saying anyway: `viewDidLoad` is a bad place for this code. `viewDidLoad` is called because the view controller has obtained its view, not because that view has appeared or will soon appear in the interface. It *might* soon appear in the interface, which is why your code has seemed to work up until now, but it might not.

The correct place for this code is probably `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. You probably want to call this code only once, though, the first time the view appears. If you want to prevent the code from being called, because you've already animated `menu` into view on an earlier `viewDidAppear` call, simply include a conditional check to see whether `menu` already has a frame within the visible view.

By the way, another reason for avoiding things having to do with frames and bounds in `viewDidLoad` is that if your app launches into landscape and this is your root view, `x` and `y` are reversed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to slide your menu in from the bottom as the Y position is pushed down initially by 200.

Usually you start by adding the view as a subview in its offscreen position and then set the onscreen position in the animation block.

And, make sure that you pass `1.0` as the animation duration.

Answer (score -2):

use those transition.subtype for different effects

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];  
transition.duration = 0.5;  
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];  
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
//transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom

[appDelegate.navigation.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
viewController *DairyVC = [[viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:nil];

[appDelegate.navigation pushViewController:DairyVC animated:YES];
```